# Divs and H tags inside of A tags

Tags: kentico

In Kentico, I am trying to put an image and an h3 tag inside an a tag in an Editable Text web part, but Kentico rewrites the code and splits the a tags, making 2 a tags, one around the image and one around the h3. How would I get this to stop?
Here is what I am trying to write:

```html
<div class="brick">
    <a href="/virtualvalley/studentresources.aspx">
        <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="/Virtual-Valley/document-library-(1)/images/default.jpg" />
        <h3>Student Resources</h3>
    </a>
</div>
```

And here is what Kentico rewrites it as:

```html
<div class="brick">
    <a href="/virtualvalley/studentresources.aspx">
        <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="/Virtual-Valley/document-library-(1)/images/default.jpg" />
    </a>
    <h3>
        <a href="/virtualvalley/studentresources.aspx">Student Resources</a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see the reply here: https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/editable-text-web-part-rewriting-code - the CKEditor is trying to fix the HTML code, not Kentico.

Comment: The samples you include are not transparent to the reader without looking at source code. Can you reformat the question to include HTML source please?